# Output on the same page as form

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms

I am doing a quick demo page for a machine learning model published as an API.
I have a form that, when the user hits submit, I would like the user to see the raw request, and the raw response, in a html div below the form.

My python looks as such:

```
@app.route('/triage/', methods=['GET','POST'])
def triage():
    form = TriageForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        session['req_text'] = form.req_text.data #probably unnecessary
        session['req_type'] = form.req_type.data #probably unnecessary
        data={}
        data['text'] = session['req_text'] 
        data['what'] = session['req_type'] 
        data = json.dumps(data) #<-- This is what I want to output
        send_request = requests.post(url,data)
        #... eventually do something with the response as well.
```

The output so far is an empty div, I want to output the raw json based on the form inputs, as well as the response. How do I dump that stuff when the user clicks submit. The tutorials I am following choose to do redirects and output other templates. Can I have a template within a template?

> form template
>
> > output template

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.

In the app.py, render template with the form.
On validate:

```
return render_template ('triage.html', form=form, output=data)
```

On the html

```
    <div>
        <h4>Output</h4>
        {% if output %}
        {{ output }}
        {% endif %}
    </div>
```